# Union all values in Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm pretty new to SQL, I hope someone can give me a lead on this issue. Or if this even possible.
In the table below:

```
order_id      order_contact      order_location       order_value
1             Tom's Business      123 Street           100
1             John's Management   123 Street           100
2             Tim's Business      543 Avenue           50
3             Phil's Business     789 Avenue           50
```

My question is: Is it possible to join/union those 2 records when the order_id is 1? The contact is the only difference between the record. I worked with Union but I think that is only possible with different columns and not rows.
I would like it to show something like this:

```
order_id      order_contact        order_location      order_value
1             Tom's Business       123 Street          100
              John's Management                

2             Tim's Business      543 Avenue           50
3             Phil's Business     789 Avenue           50
```

Is this even possible?
Thanks for your help

Comment: which dbms you are using? mysql? mssql / tsql? postgres? oracle?

Comment: I didn't understood where you need to show the data in this format.
Would be in an application view, or the query result should have only the "order_contact" column filled on the second row?
And, what is the DBMS you're using (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc)?

Comment: It sure is possible, somehow, but goes a bit against what SQL is meant for. Do you really have to do this in your database? Or could you move this different way of displaying the data to your 'view' layer?

Comment: I'm using mysql.

Comment: This is just for a report. I'm not editing the DB. It's a select statement

Comment: @ferhrosa I'm trying to join Tom's Business and John's Management in the same box

Comment: Fix it in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution using [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT order_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT order_contact SEPARATOR ' ') AS order_contact,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT order_location SEPARATOR ' ') AS order_location,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT order_value SEPARATOR ' ') AS order_value
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY order_id
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78d7ea/2/0